# Does snapping reset the plusses (e.g +4) in uno?

Tags: house-rules, uno

I wanted to know if you snap a +4 or +2 does it reset the amount the person picks up?

Comment: My understanding was that in the original rules a draw2 or draw4 function as a skip in addition to making the following player draw cards. Since the player on the receiving end is being skipped they cannot prevent or respond to this.  So, if player 1 does a draw2, then player 2 loses their turn and draws two cards.  Later player 3 can also play a draw2 which will cause player 4 to lose their turn and draw two cards as well.

Comment: Are you looking for the original UNO rules or the most commonly played rules of the UNO stacking house rules?

Comment: Your question is unclear, the word "snap" does not appear in the rules. It is unclear whether Player 1 played +2, player 2 picked up 2, and player 3 now wants to play a +2; or whether player 1 played a blue +2, player 2 picked up 2, and now player 5 wants to "snap" by playing exactly the same card (blue +2) skipping player 3 and 4s turns - this would be a house rule, not an official one. It is also unclear whether you are playing the "stacking" rule or not.

Answer (score 2):

Chaning/Snapping/Stacking draw cards does not reset the penalty amount. E.G Player 1 plays draw 2, player 2 plays another draw 2, player 3, having no draw 2 cards, must draw 4 cards.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_(card_game)) as a part of the **house rules**:

> Progressive Uno: If a draw card is played, and the following player
>   has the same card, they can play that card and "stack" the penalty,
>   which **adds to the current penalty and passes it to the following
>   player.**

Comment: You should note that stacking draw cards is a house rule and is not part of the official rules.

Comment: doesn't matter as the question holder is aware of this but i've edited anyway

Comment: From reading the question it does not appear to be stated as a house rule and there have been questions before about how the rules change due to chaining draw cards where people did not realize that they where house rules.

Comment: fair, just seemed like an obvious i want to know this, i dont care if its housed

Comment: The wiki article linked does not specify that if following this house rule that the earlier functionality of draw2/draw4 is ignored, in particular the skipping aspect. Would it not be player1 plays a draw2, player 2 has his turn skipped and picks up two cards, then later player 3 also plays a draw2 followed by player 4 having to (as a result of the house rule) pick up 2+2 cards? How is it in your example that player 2 played a card? Or is it that with this house rule the recipient of a draw2 is given an opportunity to respond with another draw2 else gets skipped?

Comment: The player that gets targeted with a +2 can stack another +2 to lead the next player with a +4. link to the wiki gives the house rule in question